# Логика в stdafx.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Я имею main.cpp условного содержания:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        Classname classname(argc, argv);
        //body
}
```

Classname описан в Classname.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

class Classname{
public:
    Classname(int ArgumentsAmount, char *ArgumentsList[]) {}
};
```

Так же stdafx.h:

```
//includes
#include "Classname.cpp"
```

Логика такова: Classname мне надо использовать во многих классах (main как пример), сам Classname использует функции многих библиотек из stdafx.h, если все оставить так, как выше, то будет ошибка на стадии компиляции

```
'Classname':'class' redefinition
```

Как можно реализовать максимальную удобность, чтобы не прописывать в каждом классе, использующем функции из Classname код

```
#include "Classname.cpp"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлять с помощью include cpp файл можно. Но это как то не очень ожидаемо. Правильно вынести Ваш класс в h файл и добавить туда `#pragma once` (или классический header guard `#ifndef #define #endif` и уже это h файл добавить в stdafx.h.

Если же Вы в каждом файле будете добавлять `#include "Classname.cpp"`, то это не избавит Вас от вышеуказанной ошибки.

Comment: а такой вопрос, если у меня код лежит весь в hpp файлах, чем это черевато, или к каким проблемам может привести (на малых проектах всё ок, интересуют большие проблемы).

Comment: я пока вижу только одну существенную проблему - увеличение времени компиляции.

Comment: а ещё) если проект собирается только с флагом [игнорировать множественную линковку] то это проблема в проекте или нормально?

Comment: я не знаю такого флага. Но подозреваю, что у Вас уже есть проблема в коде. Она просто ещё не проявилась.

Comment: я имел ввиду `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` может выразился неправильно.